# Add custom payment method processing in checkout page for big commerce

Tags: bigcommerce, bigcommerce-checkout-sdk

I'm currently working on integrating a payment method for a client. The client wants to include the option to pay using their custom payment method on the BigCommerce checkout page. I'm required to use React and Node to implement this functionality, as the client specifically wants to add a custom payment form. Could you guide me on the steps to achieve this?

Currently I need the exact direction how and where to proceed?